# error with c++ thead

Tags: c++, multithreading

this is main file for a small socket demo, I want use thread to receive server reply, but when I try to create new thread:

error message:

```
 error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "client_socket.h"
#include "socket_exception.h"

void receive(ClientSocket client)
{
     std::string reply;
     while (true) {
        client >> reply;
        std::cout << "We received this response from the server:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\"" << reply << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    try {
        ClientSocket client("127.0.0.1", 30000);
        std::string sendBuf;

        std::thread receiver(receive, client);
        receiver.join();

        while (true) {
            std::cout << "Enter string send to server:" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> sendBuf;
            if (sendBuf.compare("quit") == 0) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                client << sendBuf;
            } catch (SocketException&) {}
        }
    } catch (SocketException& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception was caught:" << e.description() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is there something wrong with thread used? thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using? This should be [working..](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d14a8f14cc6f660)

Comment: Is `ClientSocket` copy constructable?

Comment: @Sean if it wasnt, the thread constructor would still have a matching singature but it would fail to compile the part where the thread arguments are copied *inside* the constructor. There would be a different error message.

Comment: @NikSun which version of gcc?

Comment: "GCC in OSX" can suggest ancient version of the compiler. Why not just use clang?

Comment: @Ame Mertz, in osx, gcc is a clang alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have a valid thread constructor call, since there is a templated constructor for 1..N arbitrary arguments. Wrong arguments would lead to compilation errors inside that constructor, not to the error message you got. Other possible errors, e.g. failure to recoginze `receive` as a reference to the function you define earlier, would also result in different error messages. It appears that the templated multi-argument constructor is not present in your implementation of `std::thread`.

IIRC a few ywars back there were early `std::thread` implementations that took only one argument, i.e. you would have to provide a nullary callable object or function, e.g. by calling `std::bind(receive, client)`. In that case you would need to update you compiler to a more up to date version.

Comment: thx, I forget use c++11, add this to cmakelist, all is right `add_definitions(-std=c++11)`